# How to check any of multiple overloads called NSubstitute

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

**Scenario**

I would like to check if a component (the sut) logs error in a particular condition. The ILogger interface constructor injected into the component, and the Error method has 4 overloads.

So I create a ILogger mock in the Arrange and using it in the Act.

I should not expect which overload the sut is using, just would like to expect and check if any of the overload called. (that would extremely white-box, and expects far more than the functional spec.)

**Question**

Currently my conclusion is that I can not utilize the `.Received` instead I must install  callbacks for all the 4 overloads, and set a variable inside them, and in the Assert part I examine that variable.

Is any simple way to do this what I missed?

*(example)*

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldLogErrorIfEmailIsInvalid2()
{
    // Arrange
    var testEmailAddress = "dummy";

    //var mock = new Mock<IEMailValidator>();
    var validator = Substitute.For<IEMailValidator>();
    validator.Validate(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(false);
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();

    var sut = new CustomerController(validator, logger);

    var customer = new Customer() { Email = testEmailAddress };

    // Act
    sut.Post(customer);

    // Assert
    // *** Here I do not want to expect a specific overload of Error, instead any of the 4 overloads satisfies the expectation
    logger.Received(1).Error(Arg.Is<string>( m => m.ToLower().Contains("email")), Arg.Any<object>());
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the SUT and the current incarnation of the test as it relates to the current problem in a [mcve]?

Comment: Please see the example what I've added.

Comment: Ok now I get what it is you are trying to do. Given how these frameworks a designed I don not think that is possible. For completeness can you show an example of the definition of the logger overloads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSubstitute does not have built-in syntax for this, but it is possible to query all `ReceivedCalls()` and manually assert on this.

For example:

```
var errorCalls = logger.ReceivedCalls()
    .Where(x => x.GetMethodInfo().Name == nameof(logger.Error))
    .Where(x => (x.GetArguments()[0] as string).ToLower().Contains("email"));

Assert.AreEqual(1, errorCalls.Count());
```

If this this is something you need frequently you could implement some helper methods and package this up into something fairly concise I think. (Maybe `static void ReceivedCallToAny(this object substitute, string methodName, Func<object[], bool> requiredArgs)` with some helpers like `T GetItemAs<T>(object[] items)` to access arguments?)